# Pandas drop method does not work.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I want to filter a rather large Pandas dataframe (about 3 million rows) by date.
For some reason the drop method when used with boolean criteria does not work at all. It just returns the same old dataframe. Dropping single rows is no problem though.

This is the code is used initially, which essentially does nothing at all:

```
import pandas as pd

#open the file

df = pd.read_csv('examplepath/examplefile.csv', names=['File Name','FileSize','File Type','Date Created','Date Last Accessed','Date Last Modified','Path'],\
             delimiter=';', header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1",)

#convert to german style date

df['Date Created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Created'], dayfirst=True)

#drop rows and assign new dataframe    

df_filtered = df.drop(df[df['Date Created'] > datetime(2010,1,1)])
```

I then came up with this code, which seemingly works like a charm:

```
import pandas as pd

#open the file

df = pd.read_csv('examplepath/examplefile.csv', names=['File Name','FileSize','File Type','Date Created','Date Last Accessed','Date Last Modified','Path'],\
             delimiter=';', header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1",)

#convert to german style date

df['Date Created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Created'], dayfirst=True)

#select rows and assign new dataframe

df_filtered = df['Date Created'] < datetime(2010,1,1)
```

Both codes in theory should do the same thing, right?
Is one of the codes to be preferred? Can I just work with my second code? In the future I may have to add a second filterdate.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks and best regards,
Stefan

Comment: you want filtered date within the same column/dataframe or you want to retrieve in any other format?

Comment: `df_filtered = df['Date Created'] < datetime(2010,1,1)` makes a boolean-valued Series. If you want to use that to select rows from `df`, use `df_filtered = df.loc[df['Date Created'] < datetime(2010,1,1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to give index list or column names to 'drop' either rows or columns respectively.
Read [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and examples given.
Your second approach works because that is the way you filter a dataframe.
You may use it at will.